# How to find base pricing and how variables effect final pricing?

Tags: r, forecasting

I have a large set of sales data. I have the Skus and final sales price and a lot of extra information such as date, location, buyer, etc. I am wanting to make a sort of calculator so someone could enter sku and then additional information and it would give an approximate competitive sales price.

I know to do this first I would need a base price for each sku. Then I would need to calculate the effect of each factor so I could modify the base price.

Is there a way to calculate this base price to compare to what we are currently saying it is?
How do I find the treatment effects?

I am just unsure the best practice for this and how to word what I am looking for so I can find a tutorial on my own it has been a few years since I last used stats.

Comment: This sounds more like [tag:regression] than it does forecasting.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What you're basically asking is how to do predictive modeling. Would you be able to narrow down your question?